# How do I declare an environmental variable in bitbucket-pipeline.yml?

Tags: git, vue.js, bitbucket

I have a vuejs app that I host in firebase. I deploy it through bitbucket pipeline.

I can't work out how to declare an environmental variable in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml so I can access it in my application.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: node:15.2.1
pipelines:
   branches:
      develop: # develop branch 
         - step: 
            deployment: test
            caches:
            - node
            script:
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @vue/cli
            - npm install -g firebase-tools 
            - npm run build
            - ls -laR ./dist #recursively list directories
            - firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --project some-website-test --non-interactive
      master: #master branch
         - step:
            deployment: production
            caches:
            - node
            script:
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @vue/cli
            - npm install -g firebase-tools
            - npm run build
            - ls -laR ./dist #recursively list directories
            - firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --project some-website-prod --non-interactive
```

I've created a repository variable called **ABR_GUID**.

I've tried adding the following into my yml file without any luck:

```
variables:
VUE_APP_ABR_GUID: $ABR_GUID
```

I've also had a look at the following articles, but can't quite seem to get it right.

[https://medium.com/@uxjulia/environment-variables-bitbucket-pipelines-serverless-deployment-4986e7d42935#:~:text=Go%20to%20your%20repository%20settings,Bitbucket%20in%20your%20bitbucket%2Dpipelines](https://medium.com/@uxjulia/environment-variables-bitbucket-pipelines-serverless-deployment-4986e7d42935#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20your%20repository%20settings,Bitbucket%20in%20your%20bitbucket%2Dpipelines).

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/#Variablesinpipelines-Repositoryvariables

How do I declare an environment variable in this bitbucket-pipelines.yml?

Comment: `- export VAR_NAME=theValue` to answer the question in your title. I assume you actually want to _consume_ your repository variable though, in that case you just use it directly as  `$ABR_GUID` in your steps.